# Prevent Wither griefing at specific locations

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

On my Factions server, I want to allow wither raiding. My spawn recently got griefed by a wither so I used WorldGuard and some custom flags plugin to disable explosions,but that does not apply to the Wither's projectiles.

Worldguard only has a feature to disable wither block damage globally, however I only want to prevent wither block damage in a specific region; my spawn.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is vanilla minecraft right? If it is you might be able to duplicate the Bedrock block and change its texture.

Comment: What server type (Bukkit, Spigot, Vanilla, Classic, etc.) and version (1.8, 1.7, 12w10b, etc.) are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The current flags that you will need for this are the following.

- `mob-damage deny`
- `entity-item-frame-destroy deny`
- `entity-painting-destroy deny`
- `other-explosion deny`

If you're just wanting the wither damage to stop, use `other-explosion deny`

Edit: You can use those, or use these commands:

`/region flag wither_skull deny-explosions any`

`/region flag wither deny-explosions any`